# Trying to connect my org to salesforce cli via vs code, gettinbg the error : The REST API is not enabled for this Organization

Tags: visual-studio-code, salesforce, command-line-interface, salesforce-lightning

I am starting with salesforce development but while connecting my org to salesforce cli, i am getting an error like - The REST API is not enabled for this Organization.
Please find the screenshots below -

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C2YGB.png)

And also in browser it is redirecting me to this url -
http://localhost:1717/OauthRedirect?code=aPrxGfV7WpWWFnHr1BftlZq.nONCzwSN.M7wIvI5VhKlMmdWCqzFghvEPSX729wC0OnXDqB6QA%3D%3D&state=e9d1b63ebaf1
please refer the below image -

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6B50N.png)

Any solution? How to fix it?

Comment: What's your production's edtion. Enterprise, Unlimited, Group... you can check in Setup -> Company Information. Some cheaper editions have no API access (or paid extra), just config via UI. The 2nd error might be because VSCode failed to register on port 1717, maybe you have another instance of it running or another app. Check https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/256860/authorize-org-failed-in-vs-code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have probably signed up, accidentally, for a trial of Professional Edition, which does not come with API access. To try out development, sign up for a Developer Edition at [developer.salesforce.com](https://developer.salesforce.com/), which does come with API access.

If the org you are using is your (paid) business org, you should still get a Developer Edition to practice in, and be aware of the limitations of development on Professional Edition.

Answer (score 1):

I also experienced the same issue, but i resolved it by adding the port no: 1717 to the sfdx-project json file and also i did kill the nodejs process running using the windows task manager. I am able to get the login URL popping up after that.

[image]